# When using DataFrame.describe(), is there a way to output a specific mean, min, or max from column in the dataframe similar to how iloc works?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in python called merge 3 with the columns: Favorite_Count, Average_Clothing_in_Color, Percent_Car_in_Color, Favorite_Color_Percent. I've used Merge3.describe() to see the mean, min, and max of each of these categories. How could I choose to, for example, output only the mean,min, or max of one of these categories depending on what I need.

Comment: What happened when you tried `df['column_name'].mean()`?

Comment: It works as intended and gives what I'm looking for but I'm supposed to do it using only .describe(),.shape, and/or .iloc[] for an assignment

Comment: If you have questions about homework, make sure to **1) state explicitly this is a HW question** and 2) Explain the requirements; since if we don't know them, we're obviously going to give the answers we'd use ourselves. Please read the guidelines on [HW questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Can you use `loc` instead of `iloc`? See [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and, if it's not obvious how to use it for your problem, check the `type` of the return of `describe()`.

Comment: To do it with `iloc`, you'll have to remember the position of each statistic, e.g. mean is the index 1... but it's a ridiculous constraint.